# writing a loop that ends with a negative number and prints the sum of the positive numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have to write a program with a loop that asks the user to enter a series of positive numbers. the user should enter a negative number to signal the end of the series, and after all positive numbers have been entered, the program should display their sum.

i don't know what to do after this, or whether this is even right (probably isn't):

```
x = input("numbers: ")
lst = []

for i in x:
    if i > 0:
        i.insert(lst)
    if i < 0:
        break
```

Comment: That depends on the input format which you didn't specify. Is the input one line of space-separated numbers, or each number on its own line as a separate input?

Answer (score 2):

you should use input in the loop to enter the intergers.

```
lst = []
while True:
    x = int(input('numbers:'))
    if x > 0:
        lst.append(x)
    if x < 0:
        print(sum(lst))
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def series():
    sum1 = 0
    while True:
        number = int(input("Choose a number, -1 to quit:"))
        if number>=0:
            sum1+=number
        else:
            return sum1
series()
```

`while True` means that the algorithm has to keep entering the loop until something breaks it or a value is returned which ends the algorithm.

Therefore, `while True` keep asking for an `integer input` , if the given integer is positive or equal to zero, add them to a `sum1` , `else` return this accumulated `sum1`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop and check this condition constantly.

```
i, total = 0, 0
while i>=0:
    total+=i
    i = int(input('enter number:'))
print(total)
```

Also, don't use:

- `for` loop for tasks you don't know exactly how many times it is going to loop
- `while` loop as `while True` unless absolutely necessary. It's more prone to errors.
- variable names that have the same name as some built-in functions or are reserved in some other ways. The most common ones I see are `id`, `sum` & `list`.

Answer (score 0):

1. convert string to list; `input().split()`
2. convert type from string to int or folat; `map(int, input().split())`
3. if you want only sum, it is simple to calculate only sum

```py
x = map(int, input("numbers: ").split())
ans = 0

for i in x:
    if i >= 0:
        ans += i
    if i < 0:
        break
print(ans)
```

Comment: Don't give variables the same name as a builtin function (e.g. `sum`)!

Answer (score 0):

do you want that type of code

```
sum_=0
while True:
    x=int(input())
    if x<0:
        break
    sum_+=x
print(sum_)
```

Output:

```
2
0
3
4
5
-1
14
```

if you want a negative number as a break of input loop

Comment: Don't give variables the same name as a builtin function (e.g. `sum`)!